# Can someone draw a graph where each pair of adjacent vertices have different degree?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I tried for almost an hour now, maybe I'm just bit dim, so give it a try. If you too don't succeed I'll write some program to test if it's really impossible.

Edit: I was looking for graphs with minimum degree of at least 2, otherwise it would be easier... I guess?

Comment: How about [complete bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_bipartite_graph) $K_{n,m}$ with $n\ne m$?

Comment: It seems very easy to me, unless you mean a finite graph maybe?

Comment: Complete bipartite or n-partite work of course! Didn't think of that. I started with a degree of 3 and then tried making circles around it. So.. Can you also find a planar graph?

Comment: @AndroidBeginner a line with 3 points, that is $K_{2,1}$, is planar

Comment: A 3x3 grid is planar, and has every vertices of degree at least 2